# Why saying "jummah mubarakah" or "eid mubarak" is considered a bidah (innovation)?

Tags: bidah, muslim-practices

It came to a shock on me that saying have a blessed jummah (Friday) is an innovation in Islam because it has never been said by the sahabis nor by our beloved prophet (saw).

Comment: Because of the difference of opinions in the definition of "bidah", I'd like to clear out that according to the majority of the scholars, this wouldn't be a bidah even though there were no proofs about this hadith.

Answer (score 2):

Saying "Eid Muarak" or any good greetings for Eid is **not a bidaah** since the sahabah used to do it:

> Jubayr ibn Nufayr said: “At the time of the Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, when people met one another on the day of `Eid, they would say: *Taqabbal Allahu minnaa wa minka* (May allah accept yours and our good deeds).”

[Reported by Al-Albani with an authentic chain of transmission]

As for Jummah. **There is no harm in doing so**. Unless you consider this as a sunnah (keep doing it every Friday) or you think saying "Jummah mubarakh" will increase your good deeds. Then this is considered a bidahh.